# Excel insert different cell contents into multiple lines of text block?

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, concatenation, vlookup

I'm attempting to insert multiple cell values into different parts of a different cell that contains a paragraph.

A2/Length: `16"`

B2/Width: `24"`

C2/Height: `12"`

D2/Template:

```
Thanks for your interest, the measurements are below.
Length: 16"
Width: 24"
Height: 12"

If you have any other questions please let us know.
```

Hoping to call each cell as a variable and insert it at the appropriate place, not sure what function to lookup and or how to have plaintext with certain lines having functions.

Would i need to breakout each line and concat them all together?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a really long concat with newlines included as CHAR(10)